# What does empty upvote mean in reputation history?

Tags: support, community-wiki, up-votes, reputation-history

What does empty upvote mean in reputation history?
In the history view I can see some records marked as upvote, and usually there are some points. But rarelly I can see empty field there.

Comment: Your post is community wiki. So you do not get rep for votes you receive on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means either the post is [community wiki post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/187824) or you get upvotes after you reach [reputation cap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/187824).

Comment: This is not my case definitely. I've gained 10 points that day.

Comment: @MykhayloAdamovych - May be. But I answered your question for all possible cases not only for your case.

Comment: @MykhayloAdamovych [your rep tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/448078/mykhaylo-adamovych?tab=reputation) for yesterday shows two events: 1) +10 for an upvote of [this non-CW post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15638125/839601) ([link-only-answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info "what's this") by the way) and 2) empty upvote for [this CW post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8212184/839601)