# Is receiving the association bonus really a top-bar-worthy achievement?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, top-bar, achievements-dialog, association-bonus

I just dropped by Meta SO, and was very surprised to see a big "+200" sitting in my achievements in-tray:

> [image: 200 free rep!]

It had only been about an hour since I last visited Meta, so I really didn't expect such a rep bounty to have spontaneously appeared so rapidly. Sure enough, checking the achievements drop-down confirms no rep activity since yesterday. Strange.

Then it occurred to me: I recently (within the last hour) created accounts on two other Stack Exchange sites. For each, I received the 100 rep association bonus. That's a total of 200 rep. Aha.

So, the +200 seems most likely to be the result of receiving the association bonus on those two sites. Yet, there is no mention of it in the drop-down.

Do we really need to have association bonuses show up here at all? After all, it's not like receiving one is much of an achievement.

Alternatively, if the consensus is that having the association bonus show up in the top bar is a *good* thing and should be retained, can we please get some kind of entry in the achievements list so that the rep doesn't appear to have come from nowhere?

Comment: I'd much rather association bonuses not show up in those stats at all. That's a pretty useless notification.

Comment: @animuson: agreed. I originally thought that adding an entry to the drop-down was the solution, what you propose kind of occurred to me to as an afterthought (hence my original hasty edit). I've edited a bit further to change the focus.

Comment: How did you got that +200 rep ? i used mine stack exchange account and joined many other exchange sites but i do not won anything :(

Comment: @PauloRoberto: you need at least 200 rep on one account before you are eligible for the association bonus (see [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/157398) for details). I see your account with the most rep is SO with 192 rep - get another 8 rep on that account, and you should start getting the association bonus.

Comment: @Mac Great! thanks for the info

Comment: @animuson, the association bonuses need to show up in the stats here to counter the [reputation lost from placing bounties](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209467/ignore-the-rep-change-caused-by-placing-bounties-in-the-achievements-reputation). :S

Comment: But in all seriousness, I completely agree. The achievements indicator should exclude things that actually have very little to do with achievement -- association bonuses and placing bounties.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider it done.

[image: You've earned a bonus of 100 reputation because we trust you on other sites in the network]

Answer (score 4):

**The idea is to generally highlight all net rep increases.** The more exclusions to what rep increases appears there, the more confusing it gets to those who don't know all the details already:

> "I see my rep went up, but didn't do anything yet, and therefore don't
>   know why. Strangely, there's also nothing in the place that generally
>   shows me rep increases.  So... that's all confusing."

You do highlight a good point, though:

**The specific thing triggering non-upvote rep increases could be a lot clearer.**
We're considering some options to make it more obvious that the increase came from an association bonus, acceptance, etc.