# Misleading rep report

Tags: bug, association-bonus, achievements-dialog

I think this is a bug (but not a serious one).  I recently crossed the association threshold of 200.  This adds a hundred "bonus" that I had not expected.  But the bar graph icon showed 1800.  Not important, but a little surprising to think for a moment that I had jumped from 198 to 1802 for no reason!

Comment: Agree it's weird, but totally by design.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209316/is-receiving-the-association-bonus-really-a-top-bar-worthy-achievement?rq=1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The green thingy in the top bar shows the **total** increase of reputation over all SE sites. If you opened  accounts on 18 SE sites and then you got the association bonus, that's 1800 in total bonuses.

Comment: OK, but it still seemed weird.  And considering that it was below 200 on each site, each gets a bump of more than fifty percent.  Several hundred percent on the site where I seem to be quite UNpopular. :-)