# Is showing the +100 in the top bar on joining a new site with the association bonus considered intentional today?

Tags: support, top-bar, achievements-dialog, association-bonus

For years, whenever I've joined a new site, I've seen a +100 in green in the top bar on the achievement dropdown. I've always thought that this was part of the system's design. I've never been annoyed by it, but I can imagine quite a few would be.

Today, after searching for something completely unrelated, I've stumbled upon [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209316/is-receiving-the-association-bonus-really-a-top-bar-worthy-achievement) which is a feature request asking for this notification in the top bar to be removed. That request was implemented in December 2014 (a staff member tagged it as completed and didn't leave any other note). Since then, it was de-implemented at some point in 2015-2017.

Was the de-implementation intentional, and if so, why was it de-implemented? Also, regardless of it being intentional, is the current behavior preferred by the team, and if so, why?

(Note: this is not a request to go back to the prior behavior. This post doesn't express any opinion as to whether or not it should be present - it just asks neutrally about the feature.)

Comment: The OP there proposed two options. Unless I'm missing something, it looks like they went with the second option (keep the notification but make an entry for it), and that's what the [status-completed] reflects.

Comment: Just to add, in the linked post, the image states "+200" - presumably an association bonus from two sites.

Comment: Wait, are you saying that you get the notification but don't see an entry? Because that's not what happens with me. [Here's a recent one](https://i.imgur.com/XAvOegh.png).

Comment: The current behavior (at least for me) is that I get both the `+100` _and_ the entry in the achievements. Regarding the screenshot in the answer, the answerer probably cleared the `+100` before taking the screenshot.

Comment: @Sonic The notification used to disappear immediately when you load the dialog. So you wouldn't see it in a screenshot like that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That request was never completed in the way you are interpreting it. At the time, association bonuses triggered a notification but did not show in the achievements dialog - it was phantom reputation.

The "completed" part there is that we started listing the association bonus when loading the dialog, *not* that we stopped popping up notifications for association bonuses. That has never been a feature of the dialog.

Comment: Ah, that the staff member didn't post any note as to how the request was completed threw me off.