# Let me know I have upvotes even after hitting the rep cap

Tags: feature-request, reputation, notifications, daily-reputation-limit, top-bar

When you cap, you don't see any upvotes you get on your profile, therefore, you don't have any update on how your questions / answers are doing unless you look at them manually.

Capping the 200 daily rep is not a reason to stop posting here so could I get notified somehow that my posts are being voted on ? Maybe put a little `+X` in a different color letting me know that I got these votes but I won't get the reputation for it.

I can go and see in my reputation feed **inside my profile** and see it :

[image]

So I don't see why it wouldn't show up in the feed above. 
Maybe putting the feed button green without any `+X` just like when you aquire a badge.

Comment: Agreed. If we really need that silly green rep notification (which we don't, but that's a different discussion), at least make it show all relevant events.

Comment: I like the silly green rep notification: appears to be a good source of random numbers if you switch between browsers.

Comment: [Things shown in the Silly Green rep notification related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208900/show-negative-reputation)

Comment: First world problem:  Too many people voted for my posts, now I can't tell how many more votes I have :-(

Comment: In case of upvote when already capped, I would highlight the achievements in green (no number) and when opened, the upvoted post will be highlighted as "unread". :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd But that only tells me that my amazing answer was upvoted, it doesn't feed my ego by telling me _how many_ upvotes I got.

Comment: @Adnan right, but starting to add votes count will clutter the currently clean design, not sure it's a good idea.

Answer (score 22):

I'm with you on that one. I've [already suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta/207972#207972) this to be done with something along the lines of

[image]