# Notification of voting activity on MSO posts

Tags: feature-request, voting, notifications, per-site-meta, achievements-dialog

I use notifications in the "recent achivements" toolbar dropdown more to see whether people are upvoting/downvoting me than to see how much rep I'm going to get out of it.

Consequently, **it's frustrating that voting activity on my Meta.SO answers**, which of course imbue no rep, **is not represented in this dropdown**.

In fact, looking through my profile, I'm not sure whether it's possible *at all* to find out when people are disagreeing/agreeing with me.

**Could we have some way to see this activity, please?**

<sub>(Since all per-site metas have this repless feature, this is a global SE feature request.)</sub>

Comment: (Whoops) 