# How do I track voting activity on my meta.[sitename].stackexchange posts?

Tags: support, voting, notifications, per-site-meta

Meta sites (with the exception of `meta.stackexchange.com`) do not alter reputation.  Thus I do not get any sort of alert when my posts are upvoted or downvoted.

How do I track or receive notifications for voting activity on `meta.[sitename].stackexchange` posts?

Comment: Related feature request: [Make voting activity on your posts available on site metas (what you would get from rep if metas had rep)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167648/make-voting-activity-on-your-posts-available-on-site-metas-what-you-would-get-f)

Comment: Fortunately when my posts here are voted on, I come back, review the whole question and set of answers, and often go back to the main page and check out what's new.  Without reminders to come back, I don't visit the per-site metas unless there's a problem, so this is really an issue of community engagement.

Comment: I use http://jsbin.com/ximuhuzo/1, but the author's answer to the other post got downvoted for some obscure reason.

Comment: @MartijnPieters And he deleted it. I'm wary of undeleting it since it was his choice though.

Comment: @AdamDavis: it got two downvotes, which is most likely *why* he deleted it. I'd love to upvote it and ask for a few improvements, myself.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've undeleted it, add your upvote and comments and if he really wants it gone I suppose it'll be deleted again.

Comment: @AdamDavis: thanks, I had already voted to undelete it before. Upvoted, commented.

Comment: I bountied this (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167648/make-voting-activity-on-your-posts-available-on-site-metas-what-you-would-get-f) post 5 (of 8 total on this post) times with 500 rep bounties and no result (3 of these bounties were, however, removed by Nick Craver :D).

Comment: I've made a fine rep loader, look [there](http://justachat.freevar.com/rep-loader).