# Why did I get a reputation change notification?

Tags: support, reputation, bounties, notifications

I haven't been particularly active lately so when I logged in and saw a green 50 on the notification section for reputation I was a bit confused.

When I clicked on it, it disappeared like normal reputation change however the only thing in the list was a bronze badge for a popular question. I checked my reputation page on my most active sites and couldn't find anything. I'm not even sure if my reputation actually changed or if I just got a notification.

I'm not concerned about the points but if it is a bug I don't want it to go unreported.

Comment: Did you view your reputation via the drop-down on a different device (say, a mobile or perhaps a different computer) and then returned to the computer which had an already-open SE page?

Comment: @Werner I just checked it from my phone and it looks the same as it does on the computer. It seems like you are trying to get me to clear the notification from another device so I want to clarify that the notification disappeared when I expanded the drop down, there was just no explanation for why it was there in the first place.

Comment: Add this to the list of other [top bar idiocies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167648/make-voting-activity-on-your-posts-available-on-site-metas-what-you-would-get-f/238766#comment789420_238766).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely a question you bountied earlier with 50 reps was deleted and so you got those 50 reps back. Rep changes caused by deletions are not reflected in the drop down.

Try looking through your profiles and check "show removed posts" in the  bottom of reputation tabs of your profiles.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Now to figure out why my post was removed, but that's another question.

Comment: @Fr3 Was that a puzzle? :D Ok, I love puzzles then :)

Comment: There was no puzzle after I found [the question](http://superuser.com/q/713832/225086). The community user that deleted it even had a link to [the explanation of why posts are deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/192719).